# IntelliJ SBT project import problems

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm almost sure that this must have been asked and answered, but I've failed to find an answer in a forest of "almost but not quite" related tissues.

Scenario. I have an SBT project cloned from Git, but it has *only* source and build.sbt. It builds fine from a command-line sbt, but has no IntelliJ specific project files.

I do "import project", and get to a point where IntelliJ mostly seems to recognize the project. However, several problems remain:

1. The project has no SDK. This is an easy fix, as the IDE prompts to add one, but I mention it, as it might have relevance to the other problems.
2. The project (after adding an SDK) will not run. It claims to build properly, but on running, it reports "Error: Could not find or load main class blah.Blah". Now, I intermittently get this on a brand new project, and the solution has always been to pop up the SBT console and build it from there. After that, the problem typically goes away. But...
3. In this project, there is no option for the SBT console. I can start one from the Terminal, but that's not the one that solves the problem in 2) above. Normally, SBT console is available to me on the bottom line, next to tabs like "Run" "Terminal" "Todo" and the like. But it's not there, and it's not on the View->Tool Windows list (not even greyed out). However, the "SBT" window *is* offered, but that only handles SBT structure, not actual operations.

Comment: Could you tell me how you imported your project on IntelliJ, by selecting folder or by selecting build.sbt?

Comment: If you get an answer to this, I'd love to hear about it. This "feature" of IDEA drives me nuts!

Comment: @ulubeyn I think I selected the folder (which it seemed to recognize). But since your inquiry raises the topic, I'll try it again by picking the build.sbt and see if that changes anything.

Comment: @ulubeyn, that's definitely progress... Importing by selecting the build.sbt file does result in the sbt tab being available (or at least on the one test I've performed so far). It also seemed to avoid the missing SDK problem. Anyway, from there I was able to do the usual "hand build in sbt window" to make the project work correctly thereafter. Thanks!

Comment: Are these problems specific to one sbt project?

Comment: No, pretty consistent, though oddly, not 100% reliable,. It's almost like it's a timing issue, and if things happen in the right order, it works, but mostly, it's much more likely to fail than not. The "have to build by hand first time" is about 90% likely to happen.

Comment: Oh, and FWIW, that issues (#2 on my list) has been uniformly expected through all the revisions I've used since I started using IntelliJ about a year ago.